# Why the input value wont update ? when i click the send button?

Tags: javascript

I try to run the code it works for the first time but in the second time it won't work I don't know why ?
I want to make it in a way that I can send several messages  over and over

```js
var message = document.querySelector('.container');
var btn     = document.getElementById('btn');
var inpt    = document.getElementById('txt');

function AddMessage() {
  if (String(inpt.value) != '' && isNaN(inpt.value) == true) {
    message.innerHTML += `<p>${inpt.value} </p>`;
    inpt.value = '';
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" value="" id="txt">
  <button id="btn" onclick="AddMessage()">send</button>
  <p>whats your name ?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: it happens because you're overwriting html code inside div with `+=` so btn/inpt variables are no longer valid, as quick solution - move var declarations inside of AddMessage function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues with `.innerHTML`

You are assigning to `.innerHTML`. This causes recreation of the element's descendants (see [`innerHTML` "On setting..."](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#dom-innerhtml-innerhtml)):

```js
const oldReference = document.getElementById("element");
document.body.innerHTML += ""; // Assigning to innerHTML
const newReference = document.getElementById("element");

const isSameElement = oldReference === newReference;
console.log({ isSameElement });
```

```html
<div id="element">
```

As you can see, the old references `btn` and `inpt` won't be the elements currently in the DOM.

**Sidenote**: Parsing `.innerHTML` may be quite time-consuming, and its use with user input is a [security issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#security_considerations).

### [Security considerations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#security_considerations)

Especially with user input you shouldn't use `.innerHTML`, because that is an easy way to insert scripts into your webpage:

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  if (!evt.target.closest("button")) return;
  
  const input = document.querySelector("input");
  document.body.innerHTML += input.value;
});
```

```css
pre{padding:2px 4px;border:1px solid;width:min-content}
```

```html
<input><button>Insert</button>

<p>Try to input this:</p>
<pre><code>&lt;img src=""
  onerror="console.log('any script here!')"></code></pre>

<p>Then look into your browser console.
```

## Alternatives for `.innerHTML`

If you want to add elements, you can use [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), [`Element.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append), and [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", evt => {
  const p = document.createElement("p");
  p.textContent = input.value;
  document.body.append(p);
  
  input.value = "";
  
  const currentInput = document.querySelector("input");
  console.log("Is same input?", input === currentInput);
});
```

```html
<input><button>Insert</button>

<p>Also try adding some HTML, for example: <code>&lt;span>Test&lt;/span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your output element is the wrapper for all of the other elements, when you do this you are *overwriting* all of those elements:

```
message.innerHTML += `<p>${inpt.value} </p>`;
```

Visually (and perhaps even intuitively) this has no noticeable effect.  But what it does is create entirely new elements which no longer correspond to your `btn` and `inpt` variables.  Which leaves you interacting with stale objects that don't represent anything on the screen.

Probably the simplest approach would be to create a more specific output element.  For example, add another `<div>` in your container and output to that:

```js
var message = document.getElementById('message'); // reference new element
var btn     = document.getElementById('btn');
var inpt    = document.getElementById('txt');

function AddMessage() {
  if (String(inpt.value) != '' && isNaN(inpt.value) == true) {
    message.innerHTML += `<p>${inpt.value} </p>`;
    inpt.value = '';
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" value="" id="txt">
  <button id="btn" onclick="AddMessage()">send</button>
  <p>whats your name ?</p>
  <div id="message"></div> <!-- new element -->
</div>
```

Comment: that Was just perfect <33

Answer (score 1):

This line `message.innerHTML += ...`

equals to `message.innerHTML = message.innerHTML + ...`, it assigns something new to `message.innerHTML`, in other words, it rewrites the content, thus references of `btn and inpt` are lost, the originals are overriden.

```js
var message = document.querySelector('.container');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var inpt = document.getElementById('txt');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
function AddMessage() {
console.log('addMessage')
  if (String(inpt.value) != '' && isNaN(inpt.value) == true) {
    output.innerText=inpt.value;
    inpt.value = ''
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" value="" id="txt" placeholder="write your message here">
  <button id="btn" onclick="AddMessage()">send</button>
  <p>whats your name ?</p>
  <p id="output"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: that was helpful and I appreciate , But i want the input to be cleared after clicking the button send

Comment: @BidjedmedSoheybGheleb You can use ` inpt.value = ''`. You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can update only inner html for answer, not the full block with input

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        input{
            outline: none;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" value="" id="txt">
        <button id="btn" onclick="AddMessage()">send</button>
        <p>whats your name ?</p>
        <p id="answer"></p>
    </div>
    <script>
var message = document.querySelector('.container');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var inpt = document.getElementById('txt');
var answer = document.getElementById('answer');


function AddMessage(){
    if( String(inpt.value) != '' && isNaN(inpt.value) == true  )
    {
        answer.innerHTML = `<p>${inpt.value} </p>`;
        inpt.value = '';
    }
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        input{
            outline: none;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" value="" id="txt" name="txt">
        <button id="btn" onclick="AddMessage()">send</button>
        <p>whats your name ?</p>
        <ul id="list">
        
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        var message = document.querySelector('.container');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var inpt = document.getElementById('txt');
var list = document.getElementById('list');
let myList = "";

function AddMessage(){
    
    if( String(inpt.value) !== '' && isNaN(inpt.value) == true  )
    {
       myList +=`<li>${inpt.value}</li>`;
       list.innerHTML = myList;
    }
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that was helpful and I appreciate , But i want the input to be cleared after clicking the button send